# Is it possible apply audio effects to all sounds coming out of a specific audio endpoint

Tags: windows, audio-streaming, naudio, wasapi, audioeffect

I have been looking around online for an answer for some days now, without any luck. So now, I hope one of you might be able to help point me in the right direction.

###### WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:

I want to build a C# application where I can apply different types of distortion and pitching effects to all types of audio that comes out of a preselected audio endpoint.

It should not matter if the user is playing an audio stream or an audio file on their system. I want to apply effects to it before the audio leves the selected endpoint.

I have been trying to use some of the windows audio APIs like 'DirectSound' and 'WASAPI' and also the open source project NAudio. sadly all with no luck so far.

###### WHAT I AM STRUGGLING WITH:

I can't seem to figure out what windows API I should use or if I would have to make my own audio API that takes directly with the windows Audio engine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/windows-audio-architecture

Please let me know your thoughts, or if you think I am looking at this all wrong.

Comment: The magic phrase is [audio processing object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-processing-object-architecture).

Comment: @RaymondChen Nice. It looks promising. Thanks for the new rabbit hole for me to dive into :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler solution: It should be possible in a soundcard driver if it can load effects.. SB live successors or EMU based cards are the cheapest and KXproject driver is awesome for those